# Facebook SSO not working without Facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, single-sign-on

I'm implementing SSO with latest [Facebook iOS sdk](http://http:/https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), following the [official tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso).

**With** Facebook app installed, everything work great. But when I try to use SSO **without** Facebook app. I got switched to safari with following URL([app_id] is my app id).

`https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&display=touch&redirect_uri=fb[app_id]%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&sdk=ios&client_id=[app_id]`

And I was quickly redirected to following URL.

`http://m.facebook.com/home.php?_rdr`

And it stopped there showing normal m.facebook.com, without any confirm dialog.

I tried to open the oauth URL with safari inspector & changed the user agent to iOS safari, I got 302 Found with following response.

```
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2012 09:52:57 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Cnection: close
Content-Length: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-FB-Debug: lgGyyzkM/gG5wYIcaFKD/gaQjHuNGoa8u+61KNXhvdk=
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://m.facebook.com/home.php?_rdr
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
```

Any idea? After all, It works well with Facebook app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question.
It turns out that i used the old style api key, the one looks like a MD5 hash. I use the new number only key, and it works properly now.